# Basic question about my understanding of the Lyapunov equation

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the system $\dot{x}(t) =Ax(t)$ where $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$. Now let $P$ be a symmetric matrix and define $V(x) = x^T Px$. Then $V(x)$ satisfies
$$\frac{d}{dt}V(x) = -x^TQ x,$$
where $Q = -(A^TP+PA)$. Now the theorem is:

The system $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$ is stable iff there exist symmetric positive definite matrices $Q$ and $P$ such that 
$$A^TP +PA = -Q$$
Now I wonder if I understand why this is true. Here is my (probably flawed understanding) of why it is true.

If $P$ is positive definite $V(x) >0$ for all $x(t)$, and thus $V$ can be used a measure of the length of $x$. I am not sure if it would satisfy the properties of a metric though... Now If $Q$ is positive definite then $x^TQx >0$ and thus 
$$\frac{d}{dt}V(x) = -x^TQ x <0,$$
so that if we accept $V$ as a measure of the length of the $x$, the length is always decreasing, and thus $x \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$.

This is my very basic intuitive understanding of why the theorem is true. I have a few problems with my own reasoning though. The first is that I can't decide if $V$ would satisfy the conditions of being a metric. I will show my attempt of deciding this below. First let $$d(x,y) =V(y-x) = (y-x)^TP(y-x)$$

1) $d(x,y)=V(y-x) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$ with $V(y-x)=0$ iff $x =y$. This is straightforward to see due to the positive definiteness of $P$.

2) $d(x,y)=V(y-x)=(y-x)^TP(y-x) = -(x-y)^TP(-(x-y)) = V(x-y)=d(y,x)$.

3) I dont know how to show $V(z-x) \leq V(y-x) +V(z-y)$ if it is even true.

So now, if I assume the triangle equality for a moment then $V$ is a metric on $\Bbb R^n$ and thus we have that if $Q$ is positive definite $V(x)$ would decreasing for all $t\geq 0$. However, this doesn't mean that $x\to 0$ as $t \to 0$. For instance if we have a solution to $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ where $x(t) = (1/(t+1) +2 ,3/(t+2))$ it is true that the length of $x$ decreases for all $t\geq 0$ however $x \to (2,0) \neq(0,0)$.

So that is my basic understanding of why the theorem might be true but why I can't see the complete picture. If anyone could fill in the blanks that would be great or maybe there is a better way of showing this result. Thanks in advance! Sorry if my explanation is dodgy at points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition that $V$ can be used as a measure of the "length" of $x$ is on the right track, though traditionally in control theory the quantity $x^TPx$ is referred to as the generalized "energy" of the system. In particular, using $V$ doesn't necessarily provide a metric for $x$, but it can be used to tell us that the "energy" of the system is decreasing over time, which then implies asymptotic stability; if $x^TPx$ decreases over time for a constant matrix $P$, it must be the case that $x$ is moving towards the origin.

To see why the Lyapunov equation helps us assess stability, first note that by the definition of the norm of a matrix, the quantity $x^TQx$ is greater than or equal to the minimum eigenvalue of $Q$ times the square of the norm of $x$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{min}(Q)\|x\|^2  \leq x^TQx
\end{equation}
Then taking the time derivative of $V(x)$ (as you've done above) gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}V(x) = -x^TQx \leq -\lambda_{min}(Q)\|x\|^2 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (*)
\end{equation}
Now examine the quantity $x^TPx$. Again using the definition of the norm of a matrix, we see that
\begin{equation}
x^TPx \leq \lambda_{max}(P)\|x\|^2
\end{equation}
(this inequality is the counterpart to the one we used above for $Q$). Taking the negative of this inequality and re-arranging terms gives
\begin{equation}
-\|x\|^2 \leq -\frac{x^TPx}{\lambda_{max}(P)}
\end{equation}
Substituting this into equation $(*)$ above gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}V(x) \leq -\frac{\lambda_{min}(Q)}{\lambda_{max}(P)}x^TPx
\end{equation} 
Since $\lambda_{min}(Q)$ and $\lambda_{max}(P)$ are constants, we can define 
$k = \frac{\lambda_{min}(Q)}{\lambda_{max}(P)}$, giving us that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} V = -kV
\end{equation}
which is exponentially stable. Note here that because this is a linear time-invariant (LTI) system, exponential stability and global asymptotic stability both imply each other.

Edit: to see why $x \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, first note that $V(x)$ outputs a scalar, so the solution to $\frac{d}{dt}V = -kV$ is $V(x(t)) = V(x(0))e^{-kt}$; from this solution, we see that $V(x(t)) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. For simplicity, I'll write $V(x(t))$ as $V(x)$ from now on. Since $V(x) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a time $t_1$ such that for all $t > t_1$, $V(x) < \epsilon$.

Using this fact, given some $\epsilon > 0$, let us find $t_1$ so that
\begin{equation}
V(x) < \epsilon\lambda_{min}(P)
\end{equation}
for every $t > t_1$. As we did for $Q$ above, we can easily see that
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{min}(P)\|x\|^2 \leq x^TPx = V(x)
\end{equation}
Substituting this into the above inequality, we have
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{min}(P)\|x\|^2 < \epsilon\lambda_{min}(P)
\end{equation}
where dividing by $\lambda_{min}(P)$ (which is allowed since $\lambda_{min}(P) > 0$) gives
\begin{equation}
\|x\|^2 < \epsilon
\end{equation}
for all $t > t_1$ which means that $\|x\| \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I have two questions. We know that $k>0$ because $P,Q$ are positive definite thus their eigenvalues are positive, so $\lambda_{min}(Q),\lambda{max}(P)$ are positive right? this makes sense to me, however the last piece of the puzzle is this: I see how $\dot{V}=-kV$ is stable because it has solution $V=e^{-k I t}$ but how does this imply stability for $\dot{x}=Ax$. Or alternatively, why, if the energy decrease does $x\to 0$ if $t\to \infty$? Thanks again for your answer, even though I dont fully understand yet it is very elucidating!

Comment: Your reasoning about why $k > 0$ is exactly right. To answer your other question, I've edited my post and added more details. Let me know if there's anything else to clear up.

Comment: $V$ is the generalized energy, not $x^TVx$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's a really nice theorem and your proof is very nice. This theorem used to be completely foreign to me but it is really cool to understand it now and learn more about the methods used in proving such theorems. Thanks again!